# One line module re-export

Tags: rust

I'm am trying to re-export a submodule from another file from a parent module.

Give this file structure,

```
src/
- lib.rs
- module/
-- mod.rs
-- submodule/
--- mod.rs
```

...can this be accomplished in a single line?

```
// mod.rs
mod submodule;
pub use submodule::*;

// something like pub use mod submodule::*;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're asking if the `mod` and the `use` can be combined into a single line.

No, there is no allowance for combining a `mod` with a `use`.  The right way to think about `mod` is that it defines where the module is located in the module hierarchy. The fact that it also brings the module name into the namespace of the current module, as if you had written `use some_module;`, is essentially a part of that, since it would be pointless to ever write `mod some_module` *without* making it visible in its parent.

If you want to also make additional names available, there is no special syntax for combining it with a `mod`; you have to use `use`.